# How can i use multiple type of agents in a single declarative jenksinfile

Tags: kubernetes, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline, agent

How can i use multiple type of agents in a single declarative jenkinsfile.
like i have two labels.
1st of type simple label

```sh
       agent {
              label "node_name"
            }
```

2nd of of kubernetes type.

```sh
           agent {
                     kubernetes {
                            cloud 'cloudName'
                            namespace 'NameSpaceName'
                            label 'AgentLabel'
                            inheritFrom 'agent'
                        }
           }
```

And i want to select between these two based on a condition
like if some parameter is given, then run node agent , else run kubernetes agent.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is not possible exactly in the way you want, but you could work around by defining agents at the stage level:

```groovy
pipeline {
    agent none

    stages {
        stage('A') {
            when { /* some condition */ }
            agent {
                label "node_name"
            }
            steps {
                sameCodeForBothStages()
            }
        }
        stage('B') {
            when { /* some condition */ }
            agent {
                kubernetes {
                    cloud 'cloudName'
                    namespace 'NameSpaceName'
                    label 'AgentLabel'
                    inheritFrom 'agent'
                }
            }       
            steps {
                sameCodeForBothStages()
            }
        }
    }
}

void sameCodeForBothStages() {
    sh "echo 'Hello'"
}
```

The obvious disadvantage is that two separate stages will show up in the pipeline view.

To avoid duplicate code on both stages you could call a function like I did in the example.

Comment: thanks @zett42, i am familiar with this concept, but the thing is i have multiple stages and i need to affect all of them in the same way..

Comment: @Abhishektomar Another possible solution would be to use scripted stages, so you are not restricted by declarative pipeline constraints. You can use `stage('name') { }` within `script` block, but you have to replace `agent` with `node`, which has different syntax.